# FFMPEG Cutting a video and adding a watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

So, I have a mp4 video that needs 2 things to be applied on:

- Cut 6 seconds right at the middle of the video (length unknown)
- Add a watermark at the right bottom of the video

You can [get duration with ffprobe](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) and

for adding a watermark at the bottom right i use this

```
-vf "movie=/full/linux/path/to/watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]"
```

All i need in one single command is to cut the 6 seconds and adding the watermark. I'm using ffmpeg on a windows 10 system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash shell example using [`ffprobe` to get duration](https://superuser.com/a/945604/) and `bc` to get middle of duration:

```
ffmpeg -ss "$(bc -l <<< "$(ffprobe -loglevel error -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration video.mp4)*0.5")" -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0][1] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a? -c:a copy -t 6 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- No need for the movie filter to overlay. That's a method from 10 years ago. Just add your overlay image as a regular input.
- Note that the main input (`video.mp4` in this example) is used twice in the command: once in `ffprobe` and once in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: The -of and -show_entries command are both an "unrecognized option", Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Not sure if i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @razz I'll need to see your command and the complete log. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: My apologies, I should have told that I want to run ffmpeg on a windows 10 system. The example i gave in my first post is one I use in a custom script.

Comment: @razz I don't know anything about batch script, but the process will fundamentally be similar. I'm assuming you want this to be scripted and you're not just looking for a ffmpeg command (as ffmpeg alone can't do it automatically).